# Why does PNGing an image from a JPG make it 10x bigger?

Tags: png, jpeg, bmp

I have an image captured via webcam of my cat (the subject might not be important).  I've aquired it as a 31 kB JPG file.  When I open it with an image editor, then save it (without alteration) as a PNG (max. compression) it stores as a 297 kB file.

Why is the PNG file 10x larger than the original JPG.  As I understand it, opening a JPG is lossless, and saving a PNG is lossless.  So, where does all the extra data come from?  If the image comes entirely out of the small file, why does it then re-save to 10x the size on disc?

Please read this carefully.  I'm not asking why the two formats produce different file sizes from an original image.  I'm asking why opening an existing JPG then saving that exact same image as PNG is 10x bigger.  I don't think that this is a duplicate question as far as I can ascertain.

Some tests I've done:-

1. I've looked at both JPG and PNG and they look identical.
2. I've zipped both files and got cat.jpg.zip as 31 kB, and cat.png.zip as 296 kB. I take this to mean that both files are fully compressed with virtually no latent redundancy.
3. I've tried this via the BMP format as well; cat.jpg (31 kB) -> cat.bmp (922 kB) -> cat.bmp.zip (404 kB).

Any ideas regarding the mysterious extra data..?

Comment: "..opening a JPG is lossless.." sure, but *saving* it is not. When 'opening' a JPEG to view it, the entire image is decoded into memory, and uses *width * height * bitdepth* bytes of memory -- which is the same with a PNG. "I'm not asking why the two formats produce different file sizes.." yes you are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPEG  inherently produces better compression than PNG. However, JPEG trades off fidelity to the original image for better compression. PNG reproduces the original exactly.

If you go from JPEG to PNG, you are not going to see a changes.
If you go from PNG to JPEG, it is likely you ill see a lot of change.

JPEG uses a series of compression techniques. One of them, the DCT, transforms the image. This creates a subtle waviness in color. For example, if you start with a solid red block that is all one color, JPEG produces a lot of slight color variations.

PNG compression relies on finding repeated pixel patterns in scan lines. The subtle color variations introduced by JPEG can make PNG compression less effective.

The extra data you refer to is simply the difference in how the two format represent the same image.

If I take a JPEG image from a camera and convert to PNG, the result is usually about 10 times larger.
For a PNG Graphic image going to JPEG, I normally get files about 1/3 smaller.

Comment: " The subtle color variations introduced by JPEG can make PNG compression less effective" - could you please expand on this if you can?  I'm having a hard time getting my head it.  Are you saying that unpacking a JPEG dynamically introduces additional variations to those in the original image?  Is this the extra data? So unpacking a JPEG is akin to running a little program that dynamically 'paints' the image based on data within the file, whereas unpacking a PNG simply unzips the pixels?

Comment: Compressing the image initially creates variations. Have an image that is just one color, PNG, can compress that extremely well. JPEG compression will turn that image into pixels with varying colors. Using PNG on that would not compress so well.

Answer (score 2):

JPG uses lossy compression, while PNG uses loseless compression. When you convert JPG to PNG, what actually happens is uncompressing from JPG and saving the results in PNG.

The "extra data" is actually due to different algorithms used.

As for why zipped files also have different size, that's because PNG has to save all pixels(including those JPG has lossy compressed) loselessy.